# How does installing battery backwards damage a torch?

Tags: batteries

Recently, I bought a high performance torch which uses a CR123 lithium battery. The manual warns against installing the battery backward and says it "will damage electronic components".

I recall doing simple circuitry at primary school, and installing a battery backwards never caused any problems.

So what makes a torch vulnerable to a battery installed backwards?

Comment: The issue isn't so much a unique feature of your light as it is the generalizing of what you learned in primary school. Yes, basic circuits with resistors and incandescent lightbulbs have no directionality, but there *are* circuit components - generally those made out of diodes, like LEDs - that only operate in one direction. I don't know precisely what components your flashlight uses (if its an LED flashlight, that'd be a quick answer) but unidirectional circuits are very common.

Comment: @dgh thank you, it is an LED torch, so you got the answer.

Comment: @dgh could you please elaborate further on how LED may be damaged by voltage in the opposite direction?

Comment: Often there is a small electronic circuit present in order to limit the current through the LED (the battery voltage is usually too high). Since it contains electronic components including transistors it can be sensitive to inverse polarity.

Comment: Improved text: Often there is a small electronic circuit present in order to limit the current through the LED (the battery voltage is usually too high). Since it contains electronic components, possibly including transistors, it can be sensitive to inverse polarity. In case the circuit only contains a current-limiting resistor then the reverse voltage on the LED itself is relevant.  Damage of a  single LED by applying an inverse voltage does not occur until the "Zener"-voltage is reached. Then, without current limiting precautions, the current through the LED increases until it is damaged.

Comment: @Qmechanic. Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the schematic of the flashlight (torch), it's hard to say. Some might have reverse voltage protection, some might not. Since it states it outright, it probably does not. Since some of these high performance ones have integrated ICs for boosting the battery voltage from 3v (CR123) to the needed operating voltage of the (assumption) LEDs and control circuitry, reversing the voltage can cause a breakdown of sensitive parts.

There are three main sets of circuits that these advance flashlights can have.

1. LED Driver (Boosts power from low voltage battery to LEDs)
2. LED Control (Microcontroller in the Switch allowing various dimming levels or features like signal flashing or patterns)
3. Battery Charging (What it says on the Tin)

If any of these lack reverse voltage protection, they can break. And that specific one has a temperature sensor. Don't know why, probably for thermal shutdown reasons.

On the other hand, my dollar store 9 led flashlight has exactly three parts to it. 3 AAA batteries, 9 LEDs, and a simple Switch. No resistor, no current control. It depends on the resistance of the batteries, the high current load of 9 LEDs in parallel, and they often blow leds over time. Very simple, and while a practical design for it's intended use and production cost (pennies on the dollar), NOT performance oriented.

Essentially, you are underestimating the complexity of the flashlight in question, and overestimating your simple electronics knowledge.

Comment: thanks very much for the answer, the torch is a led lenser f1... i'll take good care of it and never install battery backwards.

Comment: @Howard updated.